# unix commands to search a string in .gz file

Tags: unix

I want to search a particular string in a .log file which is compressed in .gz format in unix.

Could you please provide the Unix command to search the string in a .log file which is compressed in .gz format.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zgrep`, if installed:

```
zgrep -e search_pattern file.gz
```

or you can use `zcat` with any regular filter:

```
zcat file.gz | grep search_pattern
```

Comment: You appear to be a great fan of "Gandalf", is it? Or a great fan of Lord of The Rings! Anyways, nice name, nice answer, +1

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful LOTR in general :-)